# Regex for password must contain at least eight characters, at least one number and both lower and uppercase letters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angularjs, regex, vue.js

I am using

/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z]{8,}$/

But the problem is when I add any special character like !/@/#... etc, this regex doesn't valid.

for example:

"Customer12" is valid.
"@Customer12" is not valid

I need a regex where "Customer12" and "@Customer12" would be valid.
regex would not be affected by special character (~!@#$%^&*()_+).

How can I create a regex where password must contain at least eight characters, at least one number and both lower and uppercase letters?

Comment: I havent tested @Amaarrockz solution however, going regex makes sense for compactness. I will post an answer that doesn't use regex for comparison

Comment: `(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z]).{8,}` use this regex

Answer (score 1):

Regex is superior in terms of succinctness. But here is a non-regex solution which becomes ever more so readable for the non-regex linguist:

```js
function validatePasswordWithoutRegex(pw) {
    // Regex for password must contain at least eight characters, at least one number and both lower and uppercase letters
    
    
    pw = pw.trim();
    
    // must contain at least eight characters
    if (pw.length < 8) return false;
    
    let alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    let numeric = "0123456789";
    
    
    // at least one number 
    let okay = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < numeric.length; i++) {
        if ( pw.indexOf( numeric.charAt( i ) ) != -1) {
            okay = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if ( !okay ) return false;
    
    // and both lower and uppercase letters (upper)
    okay = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < alpha.length; i++) {
        if ( pw.indexOf( alpha.charAt( i ) ) != -1) {
            okay = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if ( !okay ) return false;
    
    // and both lower and uppercase letters (lower)
    okay = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < alpha.length; i++) {
        if ( pw.indexOf( alpha.charAt( i ).toLowerCase() ) != -1) {
            okay = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if ( !okay ) return false;
    
    
    return true; // passed requirements

}

console.log( validatePasswordWithoutRegex( "ABC" ) );
    console.log( validatePasswordWithoutRegex( "hello world" ) );
    console.log( validatePasswordWithoutRegex( "he12World" ) );
    console.log( validatePasswordWithoutRegex( "12345678" ) );
    console.log( validatePasswordWithoutRegex( "123a5678" ) );
    console.log( validatePasswordWithoutRegex( "123a56B8" ) );
    console.log( validatePasswordWithoutRegex( "Hello12rld" ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex expression for
Atleast eight characters, at least one letter and one number:

```
/^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]{8,}$/
```

It you want atleast eight characters, at least one letter and one number and one special character then you can use the below expression.

```
/"^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*#?&]{8,}$/
```